# Spark - Apply UDF on few columns of a Dataset and form new columns

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset of String types and I want to apply a function over some columns of this dataset and convert them to Long or Double or Int etc. based on the column and append the new columns (or even a tuple of these columns) to the same Dataset. Can someone please suggest the right way of doing this ?

UPDATE:

The following fails:

```
ds.withColumn("newCol", Vectors.dense(strDoubleUDF(ds("col10")) + str2DoubleUDF(ds("col12")))
```

with the error

```
<console>:253: error: overloaded method value dense with alternatives:
  (values: Array[Double])org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector <and>
  (firstValue: Double,otherValues: Double*)org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
                         Vectors.dense(str2DoubleUDF(ds("col10")),
```

Comment: That sounds a bit too complicated to say anything about without some data and more detailed explanation of what you want to acheive. Maybe add expected output as well.

Comment: Sounds like "cast" function :)

Comment: @Shaido Dataset is just a column of strings .. I just want to convert few columns to Double and add a Vector of those double values at the end. In simplest form, if I have a Dataset with one row and 3 columns as "1", "2", "3", I want to add a new column with Vector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0). The strings sometimes aren't numerical values, so in my code I actually have to apply a UDF but ultimately a Vector of Double values need to be added to the Dataset.

Comment: @T.Gawęda I am past the "cast"-ing part with a UDF as conversion involves logic. What is failing is Vector-ization past that step. Updated the post with exact error.

Comment: @S.K. Ok, now it looks that UDF is needed. Please see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in support for making Vectors, so you should use UDF:

```
val vectorUDF = udf ((col1 : Seq[Double], col2 : Seq[Double]) => {
    Vectors.dense(col1 + col2)
});
ds.withColumn("newCol", vectorUDF(strDoubleUDF(ds("col10")), str2DoubleUDF(ds("col12")))
```

Comment: Is the VectorUDF taking one or two parameters here ? The way it is called, it seems like we are passing only one but the definition seem to indicate that there are two parameters

Comment: @S.K Two parameters - see edit. Too much copy paste :)

Answer (score 0):

here an example of how to achieve this:

```
val ds: Dataset[(String, String)] = Seq(
  ("1.0","1"),
  ("2.0","2"),
  ("3.0","3"),
  ("4.0","4")
).toDS()


val newDs: Dataset[(String, String, (Double, Int))] = ds
  .map{case (doubleStr,intStr) =>
  (doubleStr,
    intStr,
    (doubleStr.toDouble,intStr.toInt) // new struct/tuple column 
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion this sounds promising. However, I have about 30+ columns and enumerating in case might be cumbersome. Is there a way to do it like we do with Dataframes ... like we can define new schema with extra columns plus all old columns.      val newSc = StructType(Array(StructField(colName, DoubleType, false)) ++ df.schema.fields) and then doing df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
        df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map(ln =>
            Row.fromSeq(Seq(ln._2 + offset) ++ ln._1.toSeq ++ Seq())), newSc) .. something like this. Thanks

Comment: @S.K If you stick to the Dataframe API it's easy, just use `withColumn`  in combination with a UDF or just casting